# Optimal preprocessing in the Kuhn-Munkres algorithm

Tags: algorithms, matching-theory, bipartite-graphs

The matrix formulation of the Kuhn-Munkres algorithm for solving the Linear Assignment Problem requires a preprocessing in which the minimal values of a line be subtracted from every value in that line; here the set $L$ of lines resembles the union $R\cup C$ of the sets of rows and columns in the cost matrix $\boldsymbol{M}\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{m\times n},\ m\le n$.

- In case of square cost matrices the row-minima are subtracted first and then the minima of columns that don't contain a zero; that is described as steps 1 and 2 in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).
- In case of non-square cost matrices only step 1 is performed as explained [here](https://csclab.murraystate.edu/%7Ebob.pilgrim/445/munkres.html).

In both cases the undesirable outcome of the preprocessing is that the generated zeros are not unique in a line of the cost matrix, because if that is the case, further steps with higher complexity are required to resolve conflicts or ambiguities.

> **Questions:**
>
> - what is the optimal preprocessing strategy for the matrix formulation of the LAP in the sense of maximizing the number of lines with unique zero?
> - can the quality of the standard preprocessing be improved by adding random vertex weights to the entries of the cost matrix prior to preprocessing, i.e. replacing $\omega_{ij}$ with $\omega{ij}+\xi(i)+\eta(j)$ with $\xi()$ and $\eta()$ generating random positive values.

My guess is that the optimal strategy for generting the zeros is to select the line without zeros that has maximal difference between smallest and second smallest value because that apparently minimizes the "danger" of creating multiple zeros in a line.